# Electrical tape vs Wago connector

Tags: electrical, wiring, old-house, duct-tape

I live in Argentina where everyone use tape and nobody know Wago connectors.

Should I use tape or Wago for my house? Wago can be purchased on Ebay, not in local shops.

Comment: How much if fire insurance? And what risk to your family?

Comment: What about wire nuts? Also, Wago is a brand name. What style of connector are you talking about, push-in or ones that require lifting a lever to insert/remove the wire. I would strongly recommend the lever style over the push-in style for ease of addition//removal and strength of mechanical bond. Anything is better than just electrical tape (unless you are doing a soldered lineman's splice perhaps -- a lot more effort though).

Comment: Yes  Wago are fine if that is your choice. I also would look into some wire nuts some can take many size wires to splice. Bucanions   are a all copper and are great for splicing ground wires.  Tape is ok is old school splice and works .I have had to use that splice many times.

Comment: Everyone should keep in mind that the “tape” method means securely twisting solid conductors and using tape to insulate the splice.  It’s very different from current wirenut methodology used today in the United States.  With that thought, it’s not just taping two wires together the same way we pop a wirenut on two untwisted wires.

Comment: @Tyson -- you still need something to make a proper, gastight electrical connection between the two wires.  Old-school taped joints used solder for this...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel a wire nut is gastight?  I’m not old enough to know about the old school US methods, but the first house i owned built around 1950ish had old cloth covered romex.  All twisted connections, no solder (although I think the conductors themselves, entire length, may have been tinned before insulating).  If 2 or 3 conductors were twisted they were taped only with cloth friction tape.  4 or more conductors and they added a crimped ferrel before taping.  It was a nasty mess to undo the tape.  ((Really happy I didn’t own that house very long but it never caught fire.))

Comment: @Tyson -- that is one strange way of doing things...it may have been the tinning on the wires was melted and acted to basically spot-solder the wires in the twisted bundles together?  And I suspect a wirenut is intended to form a gastight connection, or at least something close enough that it works reliably over the long term; you simply can't make a reliable electrical connection otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

### Tape is not a connecting means on its own

Electrical tape is an *insulating* means, not a way of mechanically holding together a connection.  In fact, old school "twisted and taped" joints had a secret sauce to them: *solder*!  The idea behind them was that twisting the wires together provided mechanical stability, the *solder* wetted the wires, filled the gaps, and made a *gastight* electrical connection, and only then you applied the tape (friction tape back then) to insulate the whole shebang. Omit the solder, and you have little to no electrical connectivity.

In this day and age, we have better ways of making gastight connections.  Push-in style connectors (such as what Wago is best known for) use a spring system to grab individual wires in a gastight fashion; when designed properly, it can be quite an effective setup, even in the hands of a novice installer.  Wirenuts use spring pressure to hold a twisted bundle of wires together; while a bit more technique-sensitive than push-in connectors or screwlugs, they can be made extremely inexpensively, leading to their widespread use in some parts of the world.

There are also a couple different styles of screw-based connectors (North American style mechanical lugs and Eurostyle device and splicing blocks) that rely on correct torquing to achieve a gastight connection between a screw or screw-driven pressure plate and the wire end, as well as the old standby of compression or crimp connectors.  These rely not on technique, but on proper *tooling* for reliable joints: screw-type connectors practically require a torque screwdriver or torque wrench to get right consistently, while crimp connectors require a suitable crimping tool.