# Are soldered electrical connections code-compliant?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

I was changing a switch in my house when I found a number of connections in the electrical box that were soldered rather than secured with a wire nut.  The solder joints look very well done, the conductors were twisted together nicely and the solder itself was nicely done.  It was not some oxidized amateur mess.  These joints were then wrapped in electrical tape.

Is that something that need to be concerned about?  Would it count as being up to code on an inspection?

I am in rural Minnesota, outside city limits, in an un-incorporated township.  I do see several inspection stickers on the breaker boxes in the house, so something was inspected at one point.

**Update:** Just to add a bit more context.   The house was constructed in 1961 and was a [Gold Medallion home](https://www.smecc.org/live_better_electrically_medallion_home.htm) and as a result had lots of fancy electrical features for the day.  Much of that original wiring has been replaced with modern NM cable, however the switch I replaces was on an older circuit with wires that look similar to Romex but have a braided outer sheath and instead of a single ground there a several smaller grounds that are wound around the the other wires.

The solder joints in question were on both types of cables in the box.  So, they would have been done as part of later work.  One of the previous owners was big into Ham radio, this junction box was right outside his radio room.  In another conversation someone suggested that this was done to reduce interference, could that be a thing?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but see also: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/165897/electrical-tape-vs-wago-connector/165902#165902

Comment: Depends where you live.

Comment: It wouldn't have made a difference for radio interference, but many old Ham guys were also competent electronics techs, so I'm betting he had the requisite skills and a soldering iron there in his radio room anyway when that work was done, so that's what he used.

Comment: Certainly prior to about 1950 knob-and-tube was used, and soldered connections were the norm.

Comment: Depends on the code in the local area where you do this. No answer is correct for all situations.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### There are better ways

A wide variety of reliable splice techniques now exist. The reason for soldering "back in the day" was that manufacturing wasn't really up to making "wire nuts" and "Alumiconns" in billion quantity.  And labor was a lot cheaper.  Today, it would be nuts to use that technique, but I wouldn't condemn old work that has stood the test of  time.

I expect your electrician will see it the same way; if you presented *new* solder work done this way, forget it, but old work would be grandfathered.

### Insulation is also a problem

The usual Home Depot advice is just put a booger of PVC electrical tape onto it. Actually, the ancients used layers of both "friction tape" (tar impregnated cloth tape) and rubber or plastic tape. The friction tape's job was to protect it from physical damage, notably bare corners or burrs from punching through the tape.  *This is complicated enough that I don't advise it; in fact, I don't even like using split bolts or other uninsulated splices*. When solder was used in mains wire, this work was done or overseen by a master electrician, and the electrical inspector relied as much on personal experience trusting that master.

The layers of insulation also make the joint **uninspectable**.  If an inspector saw a soldered rattail splice today, he'd have good reason to either assume it wasn't soldered, or that it was not properly insulated.

### "Modern" soldering won't do

In mains wiring a lot of engineering is done to assure we're not wasting copper. **Wires are intended to heat up**, and are generally run at sane thermal limits.

Solder only has about 1/10 the conductivity of copper.

Now look at how modern soldering is done.  Here's a surface mount power jack.  You see the tiny tabs meant for the solder connection?

[image]

This is the mentality of *modern, electronic* soldering.  Put a tiny dit of solder there (even if you drown that tab in solder, there's just not that much tab there) and call it good.  That works because currents are small - that connector is rated for 1 amp, the limiting factor being the surface area of the solder.

It's "tack soldering", as distinct from a thorough splice like you have there, or a Western Union splice. **The problem is, when you say "soldering", everyone hears "tack soldering, like done in electronics"**. That is not nearly acceptable.  Yes, Western Union etc. splices are alright.  They are also a "lost art".

**I don't believe the Western Union splice is a lost art you should be re-creating**, because there are better ways to do this today, and it would be difficult to re-create it *properly* without apprenticing under an experienced master.

Comment: Completely agree that there are better mains wiring methods today, but your comments on soldering aren't quite right.  The temperatures mains wire is designed to operate at, 90C max and usually 60 or 75C, is nowhere near the melting point of the easiest-to-melt lead-based solder, which is 183C.  And the lower conductivity doesn't much matter since you're covering a larger area with it.  And in electronics manufacturing, they absolutely do use FLIR cameras to inspect the connections to the ethernet jacks and everything else, and the copper PCB traces can be quite thin, not oversized.

Comment: @NateS-ReinstateMonica Those are temps the wires are *supposed* to run at.  Adding low-conductivity solder throws a monkey wrench into it.  Unless the solder path has 10 times the cross section of the copper, it will run hotter than the copper. So now you're depending on the copper carrying away this excess heat.  The copper already has to contend with its own heat.  "covering a larger area with it" *It has to be 10 times the area*.

Comment: You're comparing solder to an un-cut wire, whereas I'm comparing it to a wire nut.  Obviously the solid wire will be best, but a wire nut doesn't make contact with the entire wire either, and a proper solder joint that flows into all the nooks of the wire will easily have 10x the contact area than a wire nut connection would have.  Also, the solder is very thin, so just like pigtailing a large wire to a smaller wire to fit a breaker, the short distance of the worse conductor means it won't affect the overall voltage drop much. The heat from a well made solder joint is negligible.

Comment: @NateS Yes, I think you're presuming a well-executed splice of the standard of mains wiring.  I'm saying nobody knows how to do those anymore, and in the real world what you'll get is tack soldering with small contact surface area.

Comment: Yes, I assumed we were talking about the old-school well made type, since that's what OP seems to have.  Agreed that tack soldering would be inappropriate.  Though us electronics folks still know how to properly solder wire, since we often need to connect it to a PCB or connector that only has a solder option.  It's less common than it used to be but it's far from a lost art.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica The splice in the OP's photo seems to have around 30-50x the conductive cross section as a wire. And that's not to mention the extra surface area dissipates proportionally more heat. It would be nearly impossible to make such a joint without 10x the conductive area.

Comment: Electronics does **not** use "tack soldering."  If you solder electronic stuff and just poke a little "dit" of solder into it, then you are doing it **wrong.**  If I'm piddling with stuff on the workbench and need a temporary connection, then yeah, I'll tack the joint together.  Anything intended to **stay** together gets a proper joint.

Comment: There should be **less** concern about resistance in a soldered joint than in a joint with a wire nut or just twisting.  Any place the solder can get to would have had **no** contact in a wire nut or twisted joint.  The soldered joint will therefore have **less** resistance than a joint using just twisting or a wire nut - despite solder having a higher resistance than copper.

Comment: Hi @Harper-ReinstateMonica, I'm nobody. Nice to meet you.

Comment: Hi @DoktorJ ... I've edited to try to address many people's concerns about what I said.  I'm required by the Be Nice Policy to talk like this, sorry if it comes off stilted.  Please for safety's sake revisit any mains solder connections you may have made.

Comment: @JRE I've edited significantly to address your concerns and clarify my point.  I'm not attacking electronics soldering.  I'm attacking the mentality of electronics soldering misapplied to mains wiring, because that is the only style of soldering *left*; the other craft has been dead for 50 years.

Comment: @NateS what I'm saying is the proper way to attach a wire to a PCB is not the same as attaching a mains wire to another mains wire. You wouldn't expect to surface-solder a #20 wire to a PCB and have it carry 11 amps, nor a #12 wire and have it carry 41 amps (chassis-max numbers [from here](https://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm)). Those amps would cook the solder attaching it to the board. When we tack wires onto PCBs, we expect a tiny fraction of that current.

Comment: Harper, you seem to be under the impression that *all* modern electronics are low power, and can get away with tiny solder joints, and that's just not true.  Open up any ATX power supply, for example, and you'll see tons of thick wires soldered to the PCB in a way that's very similar to mains wiring.  It's true that you wouldn't just tack those to a surface mount pad, because with wires that thick it'd rip off the pad, so through-hole construction is used.  The soldering techniques for wire-to-wire, wire-to-connector, and wire-to-board are all very similar as well, since...

Comment: ... by far the biggest factor is that the thick copper wire is acting as a heatsink, so you have to use higher temperatures for more time than you would just soldering, say, an SMT resistor on.  I'd contend that anyone who knows how to properly solder a 12AWG wire to a PCB can easily learn how to properly solder it to another 12AWG wire as well.

Comment: @NateS Through-holes make a big difference.  I don't see how anything about electronics teaches anything about traditional mains style solder splices e.g. Western Union. When the latter died, PCBs didn't exist yet and electronics bent wires over lugs (impressive contact area). The "copper wire as heatsink" strategem is limited by the fact that *the wire's thermal capacity is already spoken for in 310.15*. Using it as a heatsink for a hot-running solder joint is not NFPA's intent, and would certainly require *another* thermal derate to be added to the pile.

Comment: I meant that the wire acts as a heatsink *during the soldering process*, not after the solder joint is completed.  Not sure how a western union splice applies here, since that's just the twisting technique -- applying the solder is the same regardless of the twisting style used.  The rattail joint twist show in in batsplatsterson's answer is just as good in terms of current carrying ability.

Comment: Also, regarding your edit, the 1A limit on that barrel jack is because of the flat tab in the bottom making contact with a circular barrel, which of course results in only a narrow line of contact.  The solder tabs could easily handle several amps.  Take a look here where they're discussing how much the similarly sized TO-220 package can handle through its leads: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108538/practical-current-limit-for-to-220-package

Comment: The tangent into criticizing sound PCB assembly practices really lessens the quality of this answer.  The author should have stuck with the topics they understand, and avoided those they so obviously *misunderstand*.  Only a tiny amount of solder is needed in the surface mount case because there is only a tiny gap between the contact and the board - current isn't supposed to divert out the side of the contact, into a blob of less conductive solder and then down onto the pad, primary flow is directly from the contact through an ultra thin layer of solder into the pad just below.

Answer (score 23):

In the US, most places are subject to the NEC, here is article 110.14(B):

> (B)  Splices.  Conductors  shall  be  spliced  or  joined  with splicing devices identified for the use **or by brazing, welding,  or  soldering  with  a  fusible  metal  or  alloy.**  **Soldered splices shall first be spliced or joined so as to be mechanically  and  electrically  secure  without  solder  and  then  be soldered.** All splices and joints and the free ends of conductors shall be covered with an insulation equivalent to that of the  conductors  or  with  an  insulating  device  identified  for the purpose.Wire connectors or splicing means installed on conductors for direct burial shall be listed for such use.

The sentence about splicing or joining first could be as simple as twisting the wires together.  It's not saying there needs to be a wire nut or other connecting hardware.  The most common method seen in junction boxes is the rat tail splice

[image: rat tail joint]

There are other parts of the code that prohibit soldering on service wires and on ground conductors, so this isn't a blanket OK for all splices.  However there may be places in existing electrical installations that would not be code compliant today, but were code compliant when installed, and therefore legal now.

This has been in the electrical code a long time.  These days, nobody splices connections.  I am not sure you'd find a solder that's "identified for the purpose" available today, and 110.14(A) requires that.

At one time solder was the main way to splice.  As far as I can tell, workmanship was impeccable in those days.  Or maybe it's only the really good work that has lasted all these years.  At any rate, my experience has been the same, soldered splices are rock solid even 100 years later.

But that was a long time ago.  **When you see soldered taped connections, it's usually best not to touch anything if you don't absolutely have to.**  The insulation is likely brittle and fragile with age, and if you start messing with it, you could wind up with a much, much bigger project than you started with.

Comment: Interesting that the diagram shows the wires being twisted counter-clockwise.  I wonder if that was actually common before screw on wire nuts or if that was just a random decision by the artist.

Comment: The solder they used then was likely plain old 60/40 lead-based solder, but in the form of a *solder pot* that the twisted rat-tail was dipped in, to allow the solder to wick in and form that rock-solid splice you're talking about.

Comment: Wouldn't solder labeled for use with electrical (i.e. plain ole 60/40 rosin core) be "identified for the purpose"?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, when soldering using an iron, you'll need a tip and enough watts to heat the entire joint to the melting point of the solder (63/37 if you're really into soldering ;-) , or 60/40 otherwise). The solder will wick along the conductors just fine. A solder pot isn't necessary to make that happen. If the solder isn't wicking, then the user either needs a tip that's better suited to the joint or needs to use  a stronger iron.

Comment: I am not old enough to have worked in the solder pot days, but I have friends who did.  The usual method was to twist all the splices, then make the rounds with the solder pot, then go back and tape everything.  Using soldering irons on extension cords at every splice would have taken ***forever***.

Comment: In this day and age - I think you could probably make a job site safety officer's head explode if you went up a ladder with a pot of molten solder.

Comment: As @batsplatsterson mentioned in his answer, "Soldered splices shall first be spliced or joined so as to be mechanically and electrically secure without solder".  I checked with my local inspector before replacing some old wire in my house. He said his concern with newly soldered joints is many people don't heat the entire joint and finish with a "cold" joint, where the solder doesn't make full connection and isn't mechanically solid.  To alleviate that, he suggested twisting, soldering, then wire-nutting the connection to make sure it doesn't come loose.

Comment: @EricSimpson Then at that point, isn't the solder usually redundant and just a waste of resources if you're going to wire-nut it afterwords?

Comment: "...a solder that's "identified for the purpose" available today, and 110.14(A) requires that." - I think you're reading that wrong.  You're citing 110.14(A) but the appropriate statement is in the first paragraph of 110.14: "Materials such as solder, fluxes, inhibitors, and compounds, where employed, **shall be suitable for the use** and shall be of a type that will not adversely affect the conductors, installation, or equipment."  The part about "identified for the purpose and conditions of use" is specifically referencing not mixing dissimilar metal conductors, e.g. copper and aluminum.

Comment: @CitizenRon  I think you're right, thanks!

Comment: @JMac, that inspector wanted to see the twist & nut regardless of anything else.  Is soldering then redundant?  Probably.   Detrimental?  Most likely not.  Code compliant?  See CitizenRon, above, and other answers in this thread.

Comment: @EricSimpson Detrimental for the installer wasting their time and a bit of money using two mechanisms when they only check for one, and only one is required.

Answer (score 7):

Soldered connections are acceptable, with a few caveats...

- Connected conductors shall not be dissimilar metals
- Solder shall not be use for grounding or bonding of conductors
- All connections must be insulated to the degree offered by the wire jacket.

I don't have the NEC at hand, but this is my understanding. The third point there is key. Electrical tape is not an ideal insulation technique (it's a bit cumbersome and ends up gooey over time), so you're left with nuts or something else. If you're adding a nut, just use a nut.

In your case, I'd add nuts over the existing joints (rather than re-taping them).

Comment: That is good to know, So it looks like the taping is where we will fail here.  Fixing that might be a problem in the long run since I suspect that this box is too full.  I don't think that I could put wire nuts on everything and get it all back in there.

Comment: Actually electrical tape is an acceptable insulator, for example you can use split bolts to splice and tape them up.

Comment: I stand corrected. I'll revise to say that I don't personally consider it a good option. It's inconvenient and ends up gooey.

Comment: I tape all the time but I use several types Cambric first then 130 or linerless and a final layer of super 88. Quality tape properly applied doesn’t get gooey , cheap stuff that’s another story.

Comment: I agree that most off-the-shelf electrical tape, while perhaps *acceptable*, is not ideal. Better longevity, and you don't have to worry about the adhesive becoming gooey and the tape slowly slipping off after some years (I've seen some old 60s-era electronics where they shorted because a bit of tape slipped out of place after the adhesive became compromised)

Comment: If you do have gooey tape covering an old splice and want to make it neater, one easy way is to stick a piece of heat shrink over it -- you don't even need to remove the tape first.

Comment: isherwood -For your viewing entertainment -  Here is a video of a really good taped splice the way @Ed Beal describes.  In my area, I know of a quarry and a couple other industrial sites that insist that all splices for their motors be made up this way, many people feel that there's still nothing that holds up better to vibration than this old school method:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aW61nupfoB8

Comment: That is exactly how I do it, and have for many decades. After a few months or years it doesn’t come off that easily but is much easier with the sticky side out. If done properly this type of tape job can handle submersion and was required by the port authority (3-4 sets of inspectors there).+

Comment: @batsplatsterson - depends on the tape. The last time I did a split bolt I needed two different kinds. "insulated to the degree offered by the wire jacket" would take a whole roll of standard elec tape. - Soldering isn't the problem, not having it properly insulated *is*.

Comment: @Mazura - I am afraid I don't follow - for example 3M 33 is rated to 600V at 105*C, the instructions would have you make two half lap layers - that's not much tape?  Even the cheap Temflex is rated 600V.  Split bolts in extremely tough environments are much harder but it's really the mechanical aspects, not the insulation resistance of the tape.

Comment: @batsplatsterson - code supersedes any directions on the tape. "insulated to the degree" not in 'degrees', but in actuality. You have to develop it until it's the *thickness* of the jacket. The only thing those numbers tell you is that it's an acceptable material. It 'depends on the tape', because some tape is a lot thicker. Two laps of 33 is what you'd need *after* several mils of friction tape.

Comment: @Mazura - what article are you getting that from it just doesn't ring a bell for me...

Comment: @batsplatsterson - "All electrical connections or splices in insulated wire shall be reinsulated at least *to the same degree of protection* as the remainder of the Wire" – [Code of Federal Regulations: 1985-1999](https://books.google.com/books?id=L3qyQm9tiskC&pg=PA522&lpg=PA522&dq=insulated+to+the+degree+offered+by+the+wire+jacket.&source=bl&ots=XTFtQ53Eaw&sig=ACfU3U1dyFb34H6QvfIRCC1d1ZMe5BhTIg&hl=en&ppis=_c&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjfvoT4_p_mAhVxJjQIHZbNC9AQ6AEwCnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=insulated%20to%20the%20degree%20offered%20by%20the%20wire%20jacket.&f=false)

Comment: *All connections must be insulated to at least the same thermal degree, voltage rating, and physical protection offered by the wire jacket.*

Comment: Physical protection doesn't mean equal thickness. That assumes the same cut and abrasion resistance in each material. Let's not get _too_ pedantic. My statement was intended to cover the concept in general.

Answer (score 6):

As the other answers cover, this is allowed by code.

From a practical standpoint, it's fine *if* you have proper strain relief, such as wire clamps where the wire enters the box -- but solder connections are much less forgiving of improper strain relief than other connection types.  The reason is that solder is a very good electrical connection, but a very weak mechanical one.  Copper (or aluminum) alone can bend, flex, and even stretch a bit without any damage, so it's suitable for things that move around a bit.  Solder is very brittle and will crack and break if you try to flex it.

So if your soldered connections are between wires securely clamped in a junction box you rarely access, it's nothing to worry about.  If the wires are not clamped, such as might be the case if they're in conduit, I might add some additional strain relief or clip the solder joint and replace it with a wire nut.  Just make sure that even if someone pulls on the wire, it's not going to transfer any of that strain to the solder joint.

Comment: I would disagree about solder inherently providing a weak mechanical connection.  I recently replaced some old wiring in my house where two 14ga wires were simply overlapped about 3" - not even twisted together - and soldered.  The joint was then wrapped with vinyl electrical tape.  I used the old wires to pull in new NM cable and ended up pulling the old wire in two, but the solder joint held just fine.  A twisted and soldered joint could be even stronger than the simple lap joint.

Comment: It's not always weak, just brittle -- it won't handle bending well at all.  The way you used it, it sounds like was only putting tension on it, which it can handle reasonably well.  But also, it has a tendency to form microscopic cracks which aren't easy to see with the naked eye, but will still cause high resistance spots, so if you'd used the wire again after doing that, you might have found it failed rapidly.

Comment: Think of it like this: copper wire is a bit like plastic; quite soft and not especially strong but will not easily break when you bend it.  Solid solder is more like glass; it is hard and durable up to a point, but you can't bend it very far at all before it shatters.

Comment: @EricSimpson: If the vinyl tape wrapping was done, the the tension of your pulling may well have gone through the tape and avoided putting any tension on the joint itself.

Comment: So what about  a surge protection device, that mounts into a knockout in the main panel ?   The wires are not long enough (to reach the ground bar and main breaker) and I'd like to simply extend them with soldered connections and heat-shrink tubing (so as not to clutter up the box with 3 wire nuts).

Answer (score 4):

Code states that solder cannot be the only means (the twisting is a mechanical connection, the tape is the insulation. The one place I find solder not allowed on ground wires , on heavy duty pin and sleeve connectors is the ground pin, the ungrounded conductors are soldered and the ground is clamped (funny because this is also the failure point in most of these cords.) but twisted and soldered connections are legal but normally only seen in knob and tube wiring.

Answer (score 1):

According to rule 110.14, it is not against NEC code to have soldered electrical splices as long as it conforms to their rules. This can vary depending on local jurisdictions, but if it is considered old work, in most cases it would grandfathered in unless deemed to be a fire hazard.

If you find soldered connections in your home, they were most likely done prior to the 1940s. The insulation on old wires can become brittle over time, almost like glass and can crack just by being handled. You're better off not touching any of it unless there is a problem. Back in the early days, electricity was considered a luxury, and the installations went above and beyond modern code. Wires were isolated from the structure of the house by ceramic posts, and fed through ceramic tubes if they passed through the framing (knob and tube). The only caveat is that there is not a separate ground wire, and early outlets are non-polarized which can be a shock hazard. The old wiring is fine for low power applications such as lighting, but should be avoided for household appliances, and any electronics.

> 110.14 Electrical Connections. Because of different characteristics of dissimilar metals, devices such as pressure terminal or pressure
>   splicing connectors and soldering lugs shall be identified for the
>   material of the conductor and shall be properly installed and used.
>   Conductors of dissimilar metals shall not be intermixed in a terminal
>   or splicing connector where physical contact occurs between dissimilar
>   conductors (such as copper and aluminum, copper and copper-clad
>   aluminum, or aluminum and copper-clad aluminum), unless the device is
>   identified for the purpose and conditions of use. Materials such as
>   solder, fluxes, inhibitors, and compounds, where employed, shall be
>   suitable for the use and shall be of a type that will not adversely
>   affect the conductors, installation, or equipment.

Answer (score 1):

Not only is soldering allowed by code, but since wire nuts count as part of "box-fill" it can be a way to allow more wires in a device box of a given volume that would otherwise be permitted. Planning to avoid the need to do this is of course preferred, but it's worth knowing about.

The main reason soldering is no longer in general use is simply that it takes many, many times longer to solder a connection (and then insulate it) than it does to use a wire nut, which both connects and covers the bare wires in a single operation. At your electrician's hourly rate it would likely double the cost of a job.